# Jplayer jquery loader not working

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have used Jplayer on my website to play songs online. Below I have mentioned the link of my website

[Q-Asar Music Productions](https://q-asar.com/)

It is working fine for small songs because it doesn't takes too long to load but for songs which are bigger in size and takes time to load, in that case it generally takes very much time to load that particular song and there is no loader for that.

I just want to implement the loader in order to show the user that the song is loading and will be played in sometime. As of now it feels like nothing is happening when I tap on the play button.

Answer (score -1):

Their is no 'loader' in jPlayer. Use the events `loadstart` to load a custom spinner or something and then remove the spinner in `loadedmetadata` or `loadeddata`, whichever one suits you best.

```
 play: function() {

        jQuery('.trak-item.active').addClass('playing');

        jQuery('.trak-item.active').find('audio').attr('data-state','play');

        jQuery('.jp-jplayer').attr('data-state','play');

    },
    pause: function() {

        jQuery('.trak-item.active').removeClass('playing');

        jQuery('.trak-item.active').find('audio').attr('data-state','pause');

        jQuery('.jp-jplayer').attr('data-state','pause');

    },
loadstart: function() {
    //start spinner here
},
loadeddata: function() {
    //stop spinner here
}
```

Comment: https://q-asar.com/assets/js/jPlayer.js
I am using this js for audio player. 
Can you elaborate where I can add the loadstart function?

Comment: It's an event handler. You have already added other event handlers such as `ended`, `play` and `pause`. Just add `loadstart` like these.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
play and pause are pre-defined in jpayer library, but there is no mention of loadstart or loadeddata events in that. 

One more thing, how can I optimise the loading time for each song? It is taking longer to load on mobiles as compared to system.

Comment: Jplayer not working in native browser. What can be the possible solution for this